# I thought you were already gone

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say:

> I thought you **were already** gone

I've heard this phrase but I think that it's not correct to use **"were gone"** here.  How could I say the same thing in a correct way?

Comment: What about "were gone" makes you believe that it is incorrect? I see no issue with tense, s-v agreement, etc.

Comment: Because i thought the past participle has to be with have/has

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- "I thought you had already gone", to me, emphasizes the act of leaving, while "I thought you were already gone" emphasizes the state of not being present. So I would say, "I thought you had already gone" when asked, "How come you didn't ask me to go with you." But "I thought you were already gone" when asked, "Why didn't you make a sandwich for me too?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You mean be-participle, not be-infinitive. I don't think *he is gone* is archaizing the way *he is come* and *he is become* both are. I might even go so far as to say that the choice of *is* versus *has* to match up with *gone* might convey a nuanced distinction.

Comment: @tchrist Apologies. 'The be-perfect still persists, to a very minor degree. It is usually reserved for literary usage (I am come at the turning of the tide; he is departed; 'I thought you had already gone' is standard) but otherwise usually sounds archaic except in one or two set phrases like 'Are you finished?' (which some will argue is copula + adjective anyway).' // The majority of early examples of "he is gone" on Google (ignoring questions like this) are for song or poetic usages, or referencing the deceased.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["She is gone" versus "she has gone"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41453/she-is-gone-versus-she-has-gone). And I certainly do not consider this a topic for ELL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

> I thought you were already gone.

means exactly what it says.  No correction necessary.

As similar way to express this could be:

> I didn't know you were still here.
>
> I thought you left.

Answer (score 0):

It is linked to a common saying, "I thought you were leaving" where the speaker is present in the other's preparation to leave.

You are correct in saying that the past participle should contain have/had, but due to common usage, instead of "were leaving" or "had left (already)" or "had gone (already)/ had already gone" people also say mix them together to say, "were already gone".

The situation for this phrase on the other hand is the speaker may have thought the other had left already, but may not have been present when they were preparing to leave.

To be grammatically correct say, "I thought you'd already gone", to write how people talk you can say, "I thought you were already gone".

Answer (score -1):

First, yes "I thought you were already gone" is correct.

This is subjunctive, where you talk about things that aren't true. For instance

> Oh, you startled me! I thought you were a robber!
>
> I want to fry some chicken. Where would I be if I were a frying pan?

Comment: "Where would I be if I were a frying pan" (?) is grammatical, but in the context you described, it doesn't make much sense. "What would I do without a frying pan?" or even "What would life be like if I were a frying pan?" makes greater sense.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I guess you've never lost anything, or wondered where your spouse put things.

Comment: Oh, wow, now it makes sense, but you had to explain it to me.